# Unable to Set/Get INSTALLDIR property in "InstallscriptMSI" type project

Tags: windows, installshield

Tried set/get the INSTALLDIR property using MsiSetProperty/MsiGetProperty methods. But it wouldn't work in case of InstallscriptMSI projects . What am I missing here?

Came across in an other forum that, Installshield properties have limited access in some cases.

Comment: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2006/06/installscript-meet-customactiondata.html

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**

MsiGetProperty and MsiSetProperty properties cannot be used for deferred InstallScript custom actions, which do not have access to the active .msi database and do not recognize any Windows Installer properties. They can access only the information that has been written into the execution script.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
// Include header file for built-in functions 

#include "isrt.h" 

// Include header file for MSI API functions and constants 

#include "iswi.h"
export prototype Func1(HWND);
function Func1(hMSI)
STRING svName;
NUMBER nvSize, nResponse; 

begin 

// Retrieve the user's name from the MSI database 

nvSize = 256; 

MsiGetProperty (hMSI, "USERNAME", svName, nvSize); 



nResponse = AskYesNo ("Your name will be registered as " + 

                     svName + ". Is this correct?", YES); 


if nResponse = NO then 

    AskText ("Enter the name that will be registered for " + 

             "this product.", svName, svName); 

    MsiSetProperty(hMSI, "USERNAME", svName); 

endif; 

end;
```

Comment: Vikky,
Take the case where I want to set INSTALLDIR to non-default destination folder programatically. Apparently the script dosent recognize the property. How do I workaround with this?

Comment: @iManiac use szSDKDirectory=PROGRAMFILES^"companyfoldername\\productname";  nResult = SdAskDestPath(szTitle, "", szSDKDirectory, 0 );             if(szSDKDirectory!=PROGRAMFILES^"companyfoldername\\productname") then szSDKDirectory=szSDKDirectory^"companyfoldername\\productname";     endif;                                                              And finally set this                      INSTALLDIR=szSDKDirectory;

Comment: Im really sorry, forgot to mention. Im trying to set the property during upgrade. Your last comment was implemented already, which is during normal installation.

Comment: upgrading means maintenance mode?

Comment: call OnMaintUIBefore() function in OnShowUI() function when maintenance flag TRUE.                                              In  OnMaintUIBefore() function call                                nType = SdWelcomeMaint( szTitle, szMsg, nType );                    
if (nResult = NEXT ) then
goto Dlg_Start;
endif;                                                               //Dls_Start is the label which is defined earliar in ShowDialogs() function